# Sampling from a subset of a dataframe where the subset is conditional on a value from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames in `R`. One contains a row for each individual person and the area they live in. E.g.

`df1 = data.frame(Person_ID = seq(1,10,1), Area = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D","A","D","C"))`

The other data frame contains demographic information for each `Area`.

E.g. for gender `df2 = data.frame(Area = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D"), gender = c("M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F"), probability = c(0.4,0.6,0.55,0.45,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.5))`

In `df1` I want to create a gender column where for each row of `df1` I sample a gender from the appropriate subset of `df2`.
For example, for row 1 of `df1` I would sample a gender from `df2 %>% filter(Area == "A")`

The question is how do I do this for all rows without a for loop as in practice `df1` could have up to 5 million rows?

Comment: You also want to include `probability` while sampling?

Comment: Yes, good point - I do want to base the sample on the probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

out <- df1 %>%
         nest(data = -Area) %>%
         left_join(df2, by = 'Area') %>%
         group_by(Area) %>%
         summarise(data = map(data, ~.x %>% 
                                      mutate(gender = sample(gender, n(), 
                                      prob = probability, replace = TRUE)))) %>%
         distinct(Area, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
         unnest(data)
```

We first `nest` `df1` and join it with `df2` by `Area`. For each `Area` we `sample` `gender` value based on `probability` in `df2` and `unnest` to get long dataframe.

There are not enough samples in `df1` to verify the result but if we increase number of rows in `df1` the proportion should be similar to `probability` in `df2`.

Comment: Thanks for that - it looks promising but I get this error ```Error: Column `data` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2``` - do you know how to fix it?

Comment: i think you have `dplyr` < 1.0.0. Can you update it to latest version using `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: Yes - it worked. A follow up question. Sometimes the sample probabilities for an area subset of data are all NA because the data has been censored (in practise this is for census data). How would you update your code for these cases to assign an NA to all individuals in that area?

Comment: You can check for `NA` values using `if` condition. Something like : `.x %>% mutate(gender = if(all(is.na(probability))) NA else sample(gender, n(), prob = probability, replace = TRUE))`